# Swapping some operations to

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Assume we have got an array `arr` with all initial values `0`. Now we are given `n` operations - an operation consists of two numbers `a b`. It means that we are adding `+1` to the value of `arr[a]` and adding `-1` to the value of `arr[b]`.

Moreover, we can swap numbers in some operations, what means that we will add `-1` to `arr[a]` and `+1` to `arr[b]`.

We want to achieve a situation, in which all values of `arr` are equal to `0` even after all these operations. We are wondering if that is possible, and, if yes, what operations should we swap to achieve that.

Any thoughts on that?
Some example input:

```
3
1 2
3 2
3 1
```

should result in 
`YES
R
N
R`
 where `R` means to reverse that operation, and `N` not to do it.

input:

```
3
1 2
2 3
3 2
```

results in answer `NO`.

Comment: where is `arr[a]` and `arr[b]` in what you mentioned above? do the numbers after `n` operations need to be in equilibrum or the array? can't really work out your example.

Comment: numbers in the example are indexes in the array. So `1 2` means we are doing `arr[1]++` and `arr[2]--`.

Answer (score 1):

Let each of the array element be a vertex in a graph and the operation `(a,b)` be a edge from vertex `a` to `b` (there might be multiple edges between same vertices). Now traveling from the vertex `a` means decrease array element `a` and traveling to the vertex `a` means increase array element `a`. Now if each vertex has an even number of edges and you find a cyclic path that visits each edge exactly once you will have a zero total sum in the array.

Such a path is called [Eulerian cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path) (Wikipedia). From the Wikipedia: An undirected graph has an Eulerian cycle if and only if every vertex has even degree, and all of its vertices with nonzero degree belong to a single connected component. As in your case only all the disconnected sub graphs need to have an Eulerian cycle it is enough to count how many times each array index appears and if the count is even for each one of them there is always way to obtain zero total in the array.

If you want to find out which operations to reverse, you need to find one of such paths and check which directions you travel the edges.

Answer (score 0):

Just count the number of times the indices appear. If all indices appear in even numbers, then the answer is YES.

You can prove it by construction. You will need to build a pair list from the original pair list. The goal is to build the list such that you can match every index that appears on the left with an index that appears on the right.

Go from the first pair to the last. For each pair, try to match an index that appears an odd number of times.

For example, in your first example, each index appears twice, so the answer is YES. To build the list, you start with (1,2). Then you look at the pair (3,2) and you know that 2 appears once on the right, so you swap it to have 2 on the left: (2,3). For the last pair, you have (3,1) which matches 1 and 3 that appear only once so far.

Note that at the end, you can always find a matching pair, because each number appears in an even number. Each number should have a match.

In the second example, 2 appears three times. So the answer is NO.

Comment: Could you please show how your idea would work with this `(1, 2) (3, 2) (1, 3)`?

Comment: `(1,2),(2,3),(3,1)` ?

Comment: `(1,2),(2,4),(4,3),(3,1)` :-)